# why can not get the element's size in backbone when page first load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In CSS, the element's height and width are set to auto. I would like to get the height of this element after page first load. I check $('#minor'), and it does has clientHeight: 333, clientWidth: 826, but can not get the value of clientHeight, clientWidth, offsetHeight and offsetWidth. However, i can get other properties of $('#minor') correctly.

By the way, i can get the clientWidth of #gallery and #image_holder, although their width set to auto as well.

For clientHeight, all elements' clientheight cant be got correctly, it always return 20

Backbone view code:

```
var SubheaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'gallery',
    tagName: 'div',

    initialize: function() {
        $(window).on('resize', this.updateCss); #=> it works correctly
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(subheaderTemplate);
        var that = this;
        _.defer(function(){
            that.updateCss();
        });

        return this;
    },

    updateCss: function() {      
        console.log($('#minor')[0].clientHeight); #=> it still return 20
        console.log($('#minor')[0].clientWidth); #=> it still return 0
        console.log($('#minor')[0].localName); #=> it return div
    }
});
```

subheaderTemplate html code:

```
<div id="image_wrapper">
    <div id="image_holder">
        <div class="image_item" id="major">
            <img src="media/images/test/image1.png" alt="major image">
        </div>

        <div class="image_item" id="minor">
            <img src="media/images/test/image2.png" alt="minor image">

            <div id="cover">
                <h1>Over 196 Homes<br>Sold a Week<br>Through Real Estate</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="image_item">
            <img src="media/images/test/image3.png"alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
#gallery {
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #fefefe;
}

#image_wrapper {
    width: 87%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

#image_holder {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

#image_wrapper .image_item {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    border: none;
}

#minor {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#image_wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}

#cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 337px;
    background-color: #101010;
    background-color: rgba(16,16,16,0.7);
}

#cover h1 {
    color: #b7aeab;
    line-height: 97%;
    font-size: 33px;
    padding: 133px 0px 0px 39px;
}
```

Comment: Is the element that the SubHeaderView is appending to already inserted into the DOM when you check its height?

Comment: yes, _.defer() do this. without _.defer() I even cant get the fixed height in css

Comment: Since the id of your view is gallery, i have to ask, what exactly is on your subheaderTemplate?, images?, also just in case, check that your div actually have a height, sometimes depending on your css, it might look that is working but having 0 height, it might not be the problem, but just to be sure.

Comment: Hi Zarich, they are images, i post the html and css code as well.

Comment: Hi Zarich, they are images, i post the html and css code as well. By the way, i can get the clientWidth of #gallery and #image_holder,  although their width set to auto as well. But i cant get the clientWidth correctly of .image_item, it returns 0. I cant get the clientHeight correctly of all elements, it returns 20.

Answer (score 1):

Height and width calculations are based on other elements, so I believe the browser can't tell you them until after it has loaded more of the page. Even a `defer` may not be enough of a delay, as it's only 1ms.

Have you tried putting your height-checking code inside a `$` block, with something like this?

```
$(function() {
    alert($('#minor').height());
});
```

If not I'd try that, or possibly even:

```
$('body').on('load', function() {
    alert($('#minor').height());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`_.defer` makes the code asynchronous, but it doesn't guarantee that your image has finished loading before calling. The `<img>` will be added to the dom, but images load asynchronously and is therefore unlikely to have finished loading before you call `updateCss()`

You should try adding an `onload` handler to the image instead:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.append(subheaderTemplate);
    var that = this;
    $("#minor").on("load", function() {
        that.updateCss();
    });

    return this;
},
```

It should be noted that the load event is not standard on `<img>` so be wary.